# Exposing SQL SELECT query capability to all users: setting timeouts and limiting keywords. Can this be done safely?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.7

I am working on a tool which allows users and scripts (or, agents) to post to and query a crowdsourced database, given the user or script has deposited credit.

The query command allows the agent to specify any SQL SELECT statement, and the server will execute this statement (with a select-only sql user) and return the results. The server charges the agent based on how long the query took, and how big the returned resultset is.

I would like to use MySQL 5.7's new MAX_STATEMENT_TIME (http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/) to limit the execution of the query based on the max time cost the agent specifies. However, the agent could simply set the MAX_STATEMENT_TIME to whatever they like in the query, which would override anything the server sets before executing the query.

While it reeks of a half-baked solution, I am considering simply scanning the supplied query and refusing to run any query with the MAX_STATEMENT_TIME keyword. This way, the server could theoretically run user-specified SELECT queries, while guaranteeing that its set MAX_STATEMENT_TIME will be obeyed.

So, the first part of my question is: is this a good idea? Am I missing something vital?

The second part of my question is more general. Is there some huge, obvious flaw in running user-specified SELECT queries with a SELECT-only sql user, given I can limit their execution time?

Comment: Why would you not just expose the data via a REST API? This solution sounds like it is just *asking* for problems.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to the idea of what a REST API is, but I think I have the basic idea.

A SELECT query is a tool that can access a huge dataset while allowing the requesting agent to filter it in any way they want. I want to allow the agents this tool because I want the agents to have the power that a programmer has, when using a SELECT statement.

I could create an api, but either I'd be unintentionally limiting what an agent's script can do, or I'd be effectively rewriting the entire SELECT functionality. I want the agent to have the limitless read-only power that a SELECT query offers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the maximum value in the cnf file?

```
--maximum-max_statement_time=30
```

Or whatever is the maximum you want. If the user does set a value, it can't exceed that. From the manual:

> If you want to restrict the maximum value to which a system variable can be set at runtime with the SET statement, you can specify this maximum by using an option of the form --maximum-var_name=value at server startup. For example, to prevent the value of query_cache_size from being increased to more than 32MB at runtime, use the option --maximum-query_cache_size=32M.

(However I agreed with collosis' comment that you should include some kind of API, REST or otherwise, as this will minimise potential problems.)

Comment: I need to be able to limit the query timeout for each request the server receives. The server charges microcents based on how much is requested of it, so it should be able to charge a large amount and run a large query, or charge a small amount and run a small query.